# Execute ObdcCommand for NetezzaSQL with C#

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, netezza

I am trying to execute a command with OdbcCommand in c# but it seems i can't even open the connection. This is the data I got to create the Connection String

```
Server: APPRDNETEZZA (192.168.0.64)
Web Server: beamprdwb3
ODBC DSN Name (64bit): NZ_FUTUREBRANDS
User: MSTR_ADMIN
Port: 5480
```

This is my code

```
string connetionString = null;
OdbcConnection cnn;
OdbcCommand cmd;
string sql = null;
connetionString = "Driver={NetezzaSQL}; servername=APPRDNETEZZA ; 
database=NZ_FUTUREBRANDS; port=5480; username=MSTR_ADMIN;  
password=mstr17Uz1%4;";
sql = "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE X_STORE_GROUP_GUID_12345(" +
                        "STORE_ID VARCHAR(10)," +
                        "STORE_NAME VARCHAR(50)," +
                        "USERID Varchar(255)," +
                        "import_guid Varchar(255), )" +
                        "USING(" +"DATAOBJECT('/apnas01/vol2.nfs.Data/ap_prod/data/store_upload/scripts/12345_guid_12345')" + "logDir '/apps/ap_prod/log'" + "     delimiter ','" + "  "; ";
        cnn = new OdbcConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened ");
            cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cnn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();
            result = "Executed sucessfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = "Error" + ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }
```

The error happens when it tries to open the connection. While debugging it gave me this inner exception

> [ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
>   specified

I have the Odbc driver installed in my machine. I dont know it this is happening cuz the connection string is in bad format. I have spent many hours trying to figure it out why doesnt work. Appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

Comment: Your program build x86 or x64? There are 2 odbc configuration, one for 32bit programs and another for 64bit

Comment: @Gilberto Quintero -  what did you find out?  Did you get the problem resolved?

Comment: @paulsm4Hi Paul, the problem was within the script, the data object did not even exist, so i could not be executed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example Netezza ODBC connection string:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/netezzasql-odbc-driver/

```
Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=myServerAddress;port=myPortNumber;
database=myDataBase;username=myUsername;password=myPassword;
```

Your connection string basically looks the same:

```
connetionString = "Driver={NetezzaSQL}; servername=APPRDNETEZZA ; 
database=NZ_FUTUREBRANDS; port=5480; username=MSTR_ADMIN;  
password=xyz;";
```

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Make the entire connection string (everything inside the quotes) *ONE LINE*.  Don't break the string into separate lines.

   Or use "+" (like you did with your SQL string).
2. Copy the driver (nsqlodbc.dll?) into the same directory as your .exe assembly (path issue?)
3. Try both the 32-bit and 64-bit drivers (CPU platform issue?)

Definitely post back what you find!